# Camel CXF REST: Setup then poll

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-camel

The problem is simple but the implementation seems elusive. I want to send only once a few setup POSTs to a REST server and then begin polling every 5 seconds with GETs right afterward the POSTs was successful. What would the implementation for this look like in Camel Spring XML using the Camel CXFRS component? I don't want to write new code or a camel endpoint and would like to do this with the existing camel tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below. For details on camel components refer to [Apache camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/documentation.html)

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
  <route id="abc" shutdownRoute="Default"   streamCache="true">
            <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=100000" />
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            --setheader for Content-Type 
            <recipientList>
                <simple>https4://post url</simple>
            </recipientList>
            <log message="After Transmission " loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                logName="com.domain" />
            <recipientList>
                <simple>https4://get url</simple>
            </recipientList>
            --unmarshall
 </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Thanks @RamPrakash! Though wouldn't this cause the service to always do a post and then a get?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my comment, wouldn't your code cause it to do a post and a get every 100000ms? I was looking to have it do maybe 2-3 POSTs and then afterwards do a GET every 100000ms.

Comment: @Thirlan yes. My bad, Looks like I didn't quite get your requirement properly. Again, You could use delay between POST and GET, refer this documentation for more info http://camel.apache.org/delayer.html OR you could write multiple flows one for POST'S and GET'S ,(timing )schedule them properly to achieve your task.